# cordovaSQLite not working, Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.transaction')

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ionic-framework

This is the section of code I have pinpointed to be causing the problem:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', []).controller('StudentsCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {

  var query = "SELECT id, student_id, username FROM students";
  var users = [];

  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      users.push(item);
    });
  });

  $scope.users = users;
});
```

I have included the necessary files for `$cordovaSQLite` to work. The above code is inside of `www/js/controllers.js`, as part of the default Ionic tabbed project. `$cordovaSQLite` works fine inside of `www/js/app.js` and also works fine in another section of `www/js/controllers.js`, but the above section of code returns me this error:

```
0     610246   error    Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.transaction')
```

**Update:** It appears that `$cordovaSQLite` is equal to `undefined` here in this function, but I'm not really sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running before the Cordova deviceready event has fired. You need to wait for it before using any device functions, like plugins. In Ionic, if you use $ionicPlatform in your controller, you can do:

`$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {`

as a way to wrap code that needs to wait for it. Try this:

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', []).controller('StudentsCtrl,$ionicPlatform', function ($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var query = "SELECT id, student_id, username FROM students";
    var users = [];

    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        users.push(item);
      });
    });

    $scope.users = users;
    
   });
  
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for giving me the code and also for explaining it as well! :D