# How to integrate calendar in ionic cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, calendar, ionic-framework

I want to integrate calendar in ionic angularjs cordova application.

I use this tutorial https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/02/using-native-device-calendar-ionic-framework/

but I found this error

> !JavaScript ERROR: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'n.plugins.calendar.createEvent')
>       http://localhost:58779/js/ng-cordova.min.js:7

my controller :

```
.controller("evenementCalendarController", function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $localStorage, $location,$ionicPopup,$state,$http,$cordovaCalendar) {

     $scope.createEvent = function() {
            $cordovaCalendar.createEvent({
                title: 'Space Race',
                location: 'The Moon',
                notes: 'Bring sandwiches',
                startDate: new Date(2015, 0, 15, 18, 30, 0, 0, 0),
                endDate: new Date(2015, 1, 17, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            }).then(function (result) {
                console.log("Event created successfully");
            }, function (err) {
                console.error("There was an error: " + err);
            });
        }   

});
```

What's this error and how can to resolve?

Comment: You need to show some of the code. Did you wait for deviceready to fire?

Comment: look please i edit it

Comment: You need to wait for the deviceready event, which Ionic makes easy. See my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630013/cordovasqlite-not-working-error-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-n-tran/34632567?noredirect=1#comment57035858_34632567